# Environment variables not working in DigitalOcean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean, puma

I tried to set the environment variables in `.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, `/etc/environment` and also in `/etc/defaults/nginx` but nothing worked. Only `/etc/environment` was the file who actually responded `echo $MY_VAR` output but `Rails` application didn't picked those variables even after `nginx and puma` restarted along with `daemon-reload` other files even didn't responded in terminal (because When i do the `ssh` it renew the `LINUX session`). I'm using these environment variables in `my_app/config` folder's files. Can anyone tell a better way to make these variables work.

I'm using **Nginx**, **Puma**, **Ruby on Rails 5**, **Capistrano** and **Ubuntu 18.04**. Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you source the file again after adding variables to any of these files: .bashrc, .profile, .bash_profile? You need to perform `source ~/.bash_profile` or restart the terminal session.

Comment: Yes i did they were good for one session and when i do login to server again using `ssh` they were gone and gone mean those were in the server but not accessable

Comment: What did you put in the file to set the variable?

Comment: export VAR_NAME=value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using the [Dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), I used it recently in combination with keeping my environmental vars in `.env` (be sure to add it to your `.gitignore`). The docs for Dotenv explain how to do the setup. In `config/application.rb`, you need to add `Dotenv::Railtie.load` followed by `YOUR_SECRECT = ENV['YOUR_SECRECT']` and any other vars you have in `.env`. Supposedly, if you're using Capistrano, you should be able to `append` `.env` with other `linked_files` in `config/deploy.rb`, but I ended up having to add the `.env` file manually to the `shared` dir on my server. Nevertheless, that setup made my environmental variables available to the `config/environments/production.rb` file.

Comment: thanks ginnie. i give it a try now. but when i already put .env in .gitignore then how can i use it on staging server / production

Comment: If you ssh on to your server and go to the `shared` directory within the app that you are hosting, you can create a `.env` file there and store your ENV's in that.